# How to express Function type?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, existential-type

I am currently reading Hutton's and Meijer's paper on parsing combinators in Haskell http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/monparsing.pdf. For the sake of it I am trying to implement them in scala. I would like to construct something easy to code, extend and also simple and elegant. I have come up with two solutions for the following haskell code

```
/* Haskell Code */
type Parser a = String -> [(a,String)]

result :: a -> Parser a
result v = \inp -> [(v,inp)]

zero :: Parser a
zero = \inp -> []

item :: Parser Char
item = \inp -> case inp of
            [] -> []
            (x:xs) -> [(x,xs)]


/* Scala Code */
object Hutton1  {

  type Parser[A] = String => List[(A, String)]

  def Result[A](v: A): Parser[A] = str => List((v, str))
  def Zero[A]: Parser[A] = str => List()
  def Character: Parser[Char] = str => if (str.isEmpty) List() else List((str.head, str.tail))

}

object Hutton2 {
  trait Parser[A] extends (String => List[(A, String)])

  case class Result[A](v: A) extends Parser[A] {
    def apply(str: String) = List((v, str))
  }

  case object Zero extends Parser[T forSome {type T}] {
    def apply(str: String) = List()
  }

  case object Character extends Parser[Char] {
    def apply(str: String) = if (str.isEmpty) List() else List((str.head, str.tail))
  }
}


object Hutton extends App {
  object T1 {
    import Hutton1._

    def run = {
      val r: List[(Int, String)] = Zero("test") ++ Result(5)("test")
      println(r.map(x => x._1 + 1) == List(6))
      println(Character("abc") == List(('a', "bc")))
    }
  }

  object T2 {
    import Hutton2._

    def run = {
      val r: List[(Int, String)] = Zero("test") ++ Result(5)("test")
      println(r.map(x => x._1 + 1) == List(6))
      println(Character("abc") == List(('a', "bc")))
    }
  }

  T1.run
  T2.run
}
```

### Question 1

In Haskell, zero is a function value that can be used as it is, expessing all failed parsers whether they are of type Parser[Int] or Parser[String]. In scala we achieve the same by calling the function Zero (1st approach) but in this way I believe that I just generate a different function everytime Zero is called. Is this statement true? Is there a way to mitigate this?

### Question 2

In the second approach, the Zero case object is extending Parser with the usage of existential `types Parser[T forSome {type T}]` . If I replace the type with `Parser[_]` I get the compile error

```
Error:(19, 28) class type required but Hutton2.Parser[_] found
      case object Zero extends Parser[_] {
                           ^
```

I thought these two expressions where equivalent. Is this the case?

### Question 3

Which approach out of the two do you think that will yield better results in expressing the combinators in terms of elegance and simplicity?

I use scala 2.11.8

Comment: "something easy to code, extend and also simple and elegant". a true functional programmer!

Answer (score 2):

Note: I didn't compile it, but I know the problem and can propose two solutions.

1. The more Haskellish way would be to not use subtyping, but to define `zero` as a polymorphic value. In that style, I would propose to define parsers not as `object`s deriving from a function type, but as values of one case class:

   ```
   final case class Parser[T](run: String => List[(T, String)])
   def zero[T]: Parser[T] = Parser(...)
   ```

   As shown by @Alec, yes, this will produce a new value every time, since a `def` is compiled to a method.
2. If you want to use subtyping, you need to make `Parser` covariant. Then you can give `zero` a bottom result type:

   ```
   trait Parser[+A] extends (String => List[(A, String)])
   case object Zero extends Parser[Nothing] {...}
   ```

These are in some way quite related; in system F_<:, which is the base of what Scala uses, the types `_|_` (aka `Nothing`) and `\/T <: Any. T` behave the same (this hinted at in *Types and Programming Languages*, chapter 28). The two possibilities given here are a consequence of this fact.

With existentials I'm not so familiar with, but I think that while unbounded `T forSome {type T}` will behave like `Nothing`, Scala does not allow inhertance from an existential type.

Comment: I was also thinking about polymorphic values but I don't know if you can do something like that in scala. +1 for the covariance

Answer (score 1):

### Question 1

I think that you are right, and here is why: `Zero1` below prints `hello` every time you use it. The solution, `Zero2`, involves using a `val` instead.

```
def Zero1[A]: Parser[A] = { println("hi"); str => List() }
val Zero2: Parser[Nothing] = str => List()
```

### Question 2

No idea. I'm still just starting out with Scala. Hope someone answers this.

### Question 3

The trait one will play better with Scala's `for` (since you can define custom `flatMap` and `map`), which turns out to be (somewhat) like Haskell's `do`. The following is all you need.

```
trait Parser[A] extends (String => List[(A, String)]) {
  def flatMap[B](f: A => Parser[B]): Parser[B] = {
      val p1 = this
      new Parser[B] {
        def apply(s1: String) = for {
          (a,s2) <- p1(s1)
          p2 = f(a)
          (b,s3) <- p2(s2)
      } yield (b,s3)
    }
  }

  def map[B](f: A => B): Parser[B] = {
    val p = this
    new Parser[B] {
      def apply(s1: String) = for ((a,s2) <- p(s1)) yield (f(a),s2) 
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, to do anything interesting you need more parsers. I'll propose to you one simple parser combinator: `Choice(p1: Parser[A], p2: Parser[A]): Parser[A]` which tries both parsers. (And rewrite your existing parsers more to my style).

```
def choice[A](p1: Parser[A], p2: Parser[A]): Parser[A] = new Parser[A] {
  def apply(s: String): List[(A,String)] = { p1(s) ++ p2(s) }
}

def unit[A](x: A): Parser[A] = new Parser[A] {
  def apply(s: String): List[(A,String)] = List((x,s))
}

val character: Parser[Char] = new Parser[Char] {
  def apply(s: String): List[(Char,String)] = List((s.head,s.tail))
}
```

Then, you can write something like the following:

```
val parser: Parser[(Char,Char)] = for {
  x <- choice(unit('x'),char)
  y <- char
} yield (x,y)
```

And calling `parser("xyz")` gives you `List((('x','x'),"yz"), (('x','y'),"z"))`.

Comment: +1 and a thank you for answering the first and the third question. I didn't think of using scala's bottom type Nothing but it seems that it works!

Comment: Note: you can skip `val p = this` by using a self type in the trait